# How to hide elements on css

Tags: css, hide

I would like to hide the "Promotions" element of this panel. Could anyone help me with the code needed to do so?

https://prntscr.com/hku99v

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really post code here. But anyway adding this to your `CSS` should work:

```
#wp_dp_member_promoted_listings {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I was typing .wp_dp_member_promoted_listings {
    display: none;
} and didn't work!!!!

Comment: @anmmer Choose my answer if it helped so others can know this one is solved.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you. It's working

Comment: @anmmer You should just choose it as correct one. Click on `nike` sign.

Comment: https://prntscr.com/hkveaf   Trying to do so here too but doesn't work...any suggestions?

Comment: I'm typing #wp-dp-listing-workings-days-holder {
    display: none;
}       is that correct?